# How does BeautifulSoup create object names at runtime?

Tags: python, class, beautifulsoup

How does BeautifulSoup create object names at runtime?
Take the following code for example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = """<html>
<head>
<sid><b>Custom Tag</b></sid>
<sid><b>Custom Tag</b></sid>
<sid><b>Custom Tag</b></sid>
</head>
</html>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
print(soup.html.head.sid)
```

How is the object of name 'sid' created. Earlier I thought standard html tags are pre-created, but the appearance of a custom tag as an object name means my understanding was wrong.
My limited understanding is that bs4 first creates and object of type `<class 'bs4.BeautifulSoup'>` which the recursively creates objects of type `<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>` My question is how does bs4 dynamically name these `<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>` objects to the actual tags found in the html?

How can I replicate this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key is [`__getattr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__), a special method that allows classes to dynamically create attributes on demand.

Oversimplifying slightly:<sup>1</sup> when you write `spam.eggs`, Python does something like this pseudocode:

```
for obj in [spam] + type(spam).__mro__:
    try:
        return obj.__dict__['eggs']
    except KeyError:
        pass
return spam.__getattr__('eggs')
```

The default `object.__getattr__` just raises an `AttributeError`, but you can override it to do anything you want.

---

Here's the code from [`Tag.__getattr__`](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~leonardr/beautifulsoup/bs4/view/head:/bs4/element.py#L1043):

```
def __getattr__(self, tag):
    #print "Getattr %s.%s" % (self.__class__, tag)
    if len(tag) > 3 and tag.endswith('Tag'):
        # BS3: soup.aTag -> "soup.find("a")
        tag_name = tag[:-3]
        warnings.warn(
            '.%sTag is deprecated, use .find("%s") instead.' % (
                tag_name, tag_name))
        return self.find(tag_name)
    # We special case contents to avoid recursion.
    elif not tag.startswith("__") and not tag=="contents":
        return self.find(tag)
    raise AttributeError(
        "'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (self.__class__, tag))
```

There's a bunch of special-case code to handle things like BS3-style legacy access, but other than that, it's dead simple: `tag.spam` just returns `tag.find('spam')`.

---

If you're considering doing this yourself, keep in mind that Python also offers "semi-dynamic" attributes, which you can create by name (using [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr) at some point after construction, rather than each time they're looked up. For many projects, this is a better solution (more efficient, attributes show up in `dir` and other reflective calls, etc.). It would probably be a bad idea for BS4's mutable trees,<sup>2</sup> but if it didn't allow mutation, it might make more sense to do something like this pseudocode:

```
for node in walk(tree):
    for ancestor in node.ancestor_chain():
        if not hasattr(ancestor, node.name):
            setattr(ancestor, node.name, node)
```

---

<sub>1. Most notably, this behavior is implemented in [`object.__getattribute__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__), so if you want to completely skip the default functionality, you can even override that method. Also, I've ignored [`__slots__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slots), [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html), [special method lookup](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-lookup), how builtin/C-extension types work, etc.</sub>

<sub>2. Imagine your rename that `sid` node to `pid`. It can't just walk the ancestor chain and delete `sid` and add `pid` attributes on each one—there could be another `sid` descendant that should now take over the `sid` attribute, and for `pid`, it even depends on whether such a descendant comes before or after the current node.</sub>

Comment: @SiddharthChabra Right. And the second footnote explains (my guess at) why they chose to do it that way.